# Class created 2 times unexpectedly

Tags: php, class

I've just found a very strange problem in my project. I have a class with several methods and everything worked fine until i tried to add a row to DB using one of the methods. Then i saw that there are 2 rows were added to the DB and that's was after each query. I've started to search a problem, but everything seems right to me. Then I've started to delete method by method. many times over i've detected, that class created 2 times per request. This is my code:

```
<?
Class UpdateStates {
    public function __construct() {
        $millitime = round(microtime(true) * 1000);
        file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/test.txt', $millitime . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
    }
}

$States = new UpdateStates();
?>
```

So each time i refresh the browser 2 lines of time appears in the `text.txt`, e.g.

```
1350614391795
1350614391973
1350614634801
1350614634835
1350614640527
1350614640646
```

What's wrong with my code? Some tech info: Linux Debian 6.0, PHP Version 5.3.15-1~dotdeb.0, Apache/2.2.16.

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Did you new that class twice? Or did you include that file twice?

Comment: @xdazz This is all content of my file, and I access to it directly without any imports or requires. There are no another requests.

Comment: I would also log the method `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`.

Comment: @Jack That's it: GET 1350616585854, GET 1350616586678. From one request.

Comment: @kpotehin Then check your access log to see if there are 2 or 1 request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use firebug to see if another request is generated from the page, could happen with a unexpected HTML code or wrong url on a image, etc.

Comment: https://img.skitch.com/20121019-85judaccyfpfjebspwgg82ptbi.jpg There is only one request on this page.

Comment: Might sound little paranoid, but can you do the request by clicking the little black dot on firebug, "Preserve log upon navigation"